# Manipulating the DOM inside of an ES6 JavaScript Module

Tags: javascript, dom

I am developing a website that generates most of its content on the client side (browser) with JavaScript.
The code is divided into several JavaScript files. A file represents a module with a specific task.

I recently learned that with ES6 you can now write native modules so i wanted to test them out.

The big problem that i have is that i can not manipulate the DOM inside of an ES6 module because each module has its own top-level-scope and therefore it is no longer the window object.

Is there a way how i can manipulate the DOM inside of a module?

Edit: Added my example code that is served through a simple Node.js HTTP server.

Index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>Basic JavaScript module example</title>
        <script type = "module" src = "main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type = "button" onclick = "test()">Test</button>
        <div id = "content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```js
import {add, sub, createHelloWorld} from './lib.js';

function test(){

    console.log('+++ Started ES6 Module Test +++');

    let number1 = 3;
    let number2 = 2;
    
    console.log('Add: ' + number1 + ' + ' + number2);
    console.log('Result: ' + add(number1, number2));
    
    console.log('Subtract: ' + number1 + ' - ' + number2);
    console.log('Result: ' + sub(number1, number2));
    
    createHelloWorld();

    console.log('+++ End ES6 Module Test +++');

}
```

lib.js:

```js
function add(a, b){
    let result = a + b;
    return result;
}

function sub(a, b){
    let result = a - b;
    return result;
}

function createHelloWorld(){
    let div = document.getElementById('content');
    div.innerHTML = 'Hello World! I am a ES6 Module!';
}

export {add, sub, createHelloWorld};
```

When i click the button i get:
"ReferenceError: test is not defined".

**Solution:**

Index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>Basic JavaScript module example</title>
        <script type = "module" src = "main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id = "test" type = "button">Test</button>
        <div id = "content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```js
import {add, sub, createHelloWorld} from './lib.js';

window.onload = init();

function init(){
    let button = document.getElementById('Test');
    button.addEventListener('click', test);
}


function test(){

    console.log('+++ Started ES6 Module Test +++');

    let number1 = 3;
    let number2 = 2;
    
    console.log('Add: ' + number1 + ' + ' + number2);
    console.log('Result: ' + add(number1, number2));
    
    console.log('Subtract: ' + number1 + ' - ' + number2);
    console.log('Result: ' + sub(number1, number2));
    
    createHelloWorld();

    console.log('+++ End ES6 Module Test +++');

}
```

lib.js: no changes

Comment: The `window` and `document` objects are still perfectly accessible in the global scope. Your problem is with accessing the function `test` that was declared inside a module from an inline event handler. Don't do that, use `addEventListener` from your main module instead.

Comment: @Bergi thank you very much. This detail solved my last problem with ES6 modules. Now i can finally transform my pseudo modules into real ones! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your premise is wrong.

At the top level of an ES6 module, a `var` variable or function declaration will be scoped to the module and will not be a global or a member of the `window` object.

The `window` object is still accessible both explicitly (`window.document.getElementById`) and implicitly (`document.getElementById`).

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing up my misconception but i still have a problem in my code that i just can not pinpoint. I would be very grateful if you could take a look at it.